Miter angle on side edges to make a glass pyramid
I am making a square pyramid out of 1/4 inch glass and could use some help determining the miter angle on the triangle pieces. The bottom edge length is 48 inches and the slant height is 66.5 inches which will make the overall height 62 inches. What angle do I need to miter the side lengths to fit together perfectly and what angle does the bottom edge need to be mitered at to sit tight to the ground?

This may be better asked on the Woodworking SE site, though it's about glass, or Math SE to investigate the math formulas for a pyramid.

I’m voting to close this question because it's about trigonometry and not home improvement. See https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/pyramid-angle, for example. Divide all angles by 2 to get your miter angles.

Your sides are ascending at about a 68-degree angle from the floor, so a 22-degree miter would create a flat-to-the-ground edge. Between your faces, there is a 97.4-degree angle, meaning you would need to miter them to 48.7 degrees to fit together.
That being said, it's not clear how you're planning to attach these pieces together. These angles are going to be hard to miter into 1/4" glass, and it's not easy to attach such large pieces of glass together, as they're much too big for me to trust glue to hold.  The easier way to construct such a structure would likely be to forgo mitering and either solder the faces together (like you would with stained glass) or attach them to a metal frame. These options might not be as aesthetically pleasing, but they will be easier and probably stronger.

Thank you for these answers. May I ask how you got to the 97.4 degree face-to-face angle? I couldnt find that angle on any of the pyramid calculators
